# Clarifying the proof of a lemma used in primary decomposition theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

consider the following proof of the lemma

> **Lemma 9.4.5.** *Suppose $T\colon V\to V$ is al inear map, $f(t)\in\mathbb{F}[t]$ satisfies $f(T)=0$, and $f(t)=g(t)h(t)$ with $\gcd(g(t),h(t))=1$. Then $$V=\mathrm{Ker}(g(t))\oplus\mathrm{Ker}(h(t)).$$*
>
> *Proof.* For suitable polynomials $a(t),b(t)\in\mathbb{F}[t]$ we have $$1=g(t)a(t)+h(t)b(t),$$ and so, $$\mathrm{Id} = g(T)\circ a(T)+h(T)\circ b(T).$$
> For every $v$ we now have $$v=g(T)\circ a(T)v + h(T)\circ b(T)v.$$
> We note that $g(T)\circ(T)v\in\mathrm{Ker}(h(T))$, $h(T)\circ b(T)v\in \mathrm{Ker}(g(T))$. Therefore, $$V=\mathrm{Ker}(h(T))+\mathrm{Ker}(g(T)).$$Suppose that $v\in\mathrm{Ker}(g(T))\cap \mathrm{Ker}(h(T))$. Then $v=g(T)\circ a(T)v + h(T)\circ b(T)v = a(T)\circ g(T)v + b(T)\circ h(T)v = 0+0 = 0$.  Thus, $$V=\mathrm{Ker}(h(T))\oplus\mathrm{Ker}(g(T)).$$

I don't understand why $g(T) \circ a(T)v \in Ker(h(T))$ and that $h(T) \circ b(T)v \in Ker(g(T))$

Comment: Both are a consequence of $0=f(T) = g(T) \circ h(T)$. Note that even though composition of operators is far from commutative, every operator commutes with itself, so $g(T) \circ h(T) = h(T) \circ g(T)$

Comment: Please don't post images; they cannot be searched, and they present a barrier to people on some interfaces.